# What is causing the syntax error in this loop?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I am trying to create a loop if a negative number is entered to prompt the user to re-enter a valid rating, but I keep receiving a syntax error can someone help point out which part does not look right. I am new to this so it's going over my head. Thanks in advance.

```
def detailLoop():
    global numOfStars

    if (rating >4):
        print ("Out of range. ")
        rating = float(input("Enter a star rating or a negative number to quit: ")

    elif (numOfStars >= lowestRating) and (numOfStars <= maxRating):
        rating=rating+numOfStars
        count=count+1
    
    # If Negative Value Is Entered
    else: (numOfStars<0):
        print("End of Program")
    
    return
```

Comment: Your indentation is a bit wonky, so it's hard to know exactly what's going on.  But the code after the final `else:` looks very wrong.

Comment: Simply a missing `)`.

Comment: Small hint: `(numOfStars >= lowestRating) and (numOfStars <= maxRating)` can be written as `lowestRating <= numOfStars <= maxRating`. And according to the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) it should be written as `lowest_rating <= number_of_stars <= max_rating`.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring your indentation, your problem is probably with your `else` statement. You don't have to specify a condition after the else statement. So it should either be

```py
else:
    print("End of Program")
```

or

```py
elif numOfStars < 0:
    print("End of Program")
```

and as @Klaus has pointed out you're also missing a `)` at the end of your input line

```py
rating = float(input("Enter a star rating or a negative number to quit: "))
```

Comment: I got everything to work now. Thanks for the help.